# How to access Office File menu items inside 'SaveAs'?

Tags: vba, ms-office

I am trying to access office menu items (like File->SaveAs->OneDrive).

I can access `SaveAs` with:

```
CommandBars("menu bar").Controls("file").Controls("save as...")
```

but couldn't find a way to access **items inside SaveAs** like `OneDrive`, `This PC` etc.

[image]

Does anybody knows how can I access these menu controls ?

Comment: With Excel 2016, I needed to use `Application.CommandBars("Document").Controls("Save &As...")`.

But I don't have the faintest clue of how you managed not have an error with `.Controls("file").Controls("save as...")` as Control is not a member of the properties of itself...

I think it's not possible to go deeper than this that way!

Comment: I tried this on Word 2016, may be there is some difference in Word and Excel behavior. And as you mentioned, if it's not possible to to go deeper than this "that way". Is there any other way ?

Comment: Maybe with `Application.OpenFileDialog` but I don't think so... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/office/ff840210.aspx

Comment: Maybe just save to the OneDrive folder manually? https://superuser.com/questions/667336/how-do-i-detect-the-location-of-onedrive-desktop-client-folder